# Error: Bad Twitter streaming request: 401 using Twit

Tags: javascript, json, api, twitter

This is the code that is not working:

```
var Twit = require('twit'); //Using Twit
    var config = require('./config'); //Loading tokens
    var T = new Twit(config); //Applying tokens

    var stream = T.stream('user');
    console.log("" + T.getAuth().name);
    //console.log("stream init");

    function followed(eventMsg) {
        console.log("function called");
        var name = eventMsg.source.screen_name;
        makeTweet("thx for follow @" + name);
    };

    stream.on('tweet', followed);
```

I am getting the error code in the title, however this *does* work:

```
function makeTweet(text) {
    var tweet = {
        status: text
    };

    function tweeted(err, data, response) {
        if(!err) {
            console.log("Tweet posted");
        } else {
            console.log("FAIL!");
        }
    }

    T.post('statuses/update', tweet, tweeted);
}
```

Do you have any idea what could help?
I already tried:
- Regenerating the access tokens
- Using different stream endingPoints
- using "app_only_auth:        true" in config.json

Answer (score 1):

Twitter user streams are no longer available and [were retired on August 23rd, 2018](https://twittercommunity.com/t/building-on-site-streams-user-streams-or-direct-messages-action-required-to-preserve-and-prevent-disruption-to-your-twitter-integration/105736/). This code will not work. You will need to use the Account Activity API instead.

Additionally, your code would violate Twitter’s automation rules. You should check those before writing a bot to automatically Tweet to new followers.

Comment: Yeah i've already read those. This was part of some troubleshooting. I assume i cannot use twit anymore, can i?

Comment: You'll need to check whether twit has added support for the Account Activity API.